# @Transactional not woking in JPA entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a static method in the entity

```
@Transactional
public static void updateState() {
    entityManager().createNativeQuery("UPDATE TABLEA SET hide = 1 WHERE id= 1").executeUpdate();
}
```

But when I call the method, I catch a exception say the update statement need a transaction.

Am I using the `@Transactional` in the wrong way?

Comment: have u defined any annotation driven transaction manager in your config?

Comment: There are 2 things wrong, first `@Transactional` doesn't work for static methods, second it only works on Spring Managed beans, I doubt your JPA entity is Spring Managed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to make your Entity a fat domain model (as opposed to thin models that are most common in the Java EE world) following the Active Record pattern.
What you are trying to do will not work as is in Spring.

If you refactor your method to not be static (first problem) then one way to get `@Transactional` working on a JPA entity is to use the `@Configurable` annotation from Spring (making it managed by Spring - therefore fixing the second problem), along with load time weaving and a Java agent. See [this](http://www.olivergierke.de/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/) and [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/spring-configurable-magic.html) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try with the annotation:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
```

Comment: If you read the documentation, you would find that specifying `readOnly=true` is only a **hint** to hibernate to attempt to perform the operation with certain (database specific) optimisations that only work if you aren't changing any data. Specifying `readOnly=false` is utterly redundant.

Comment: Not knowing what his configuration are, specifying readOnly=false makes it clear! The problem with these tools like spring/hibernate etc.. is that people think this is redundant, lets generate code or this annotation does magic, however reading the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html makes it clear that this annotation takes precedence of every other configuration, suppose a readOnly=true in spring configuration file for this method, we dont have any other information from his question...